# How to add plain text node to drupal form?

Tags: forms, drupal

I'm trying to add a plain text node in a custom drupal form. The purpose is to only dispay some static text.

The problem is - im not aware of any such way to do it.

I have used 'description' but that HAS to be attached to a form element.

Is there any way to simply display some text as part of a form?

Eg:

The following will test your ability on so and so. . . .

etc...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add text using the [`markup` form element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup).

> **Description**: Generate generic markup for display inside forms.

Example from the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup):

```
$form['contact_information'] = array(

  '#markup' => variable_get('contact_form_information',
t('You can leave us a message using the contact form
below.')),

);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Exactly what I've been looking for!